# How do you create methods using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

How do you create a method that accepts a one-dimensional array and a string as its arguments?

- Use a linear search to identify if the product is in the array. If the name is in the array, the method should return the position. If the number is not in the array, the method should return-1.
- When the user enters the name of a product, the program should step through the ArrayList.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>();

    products.add("Pencil pouch");
    products.add("pen");
    products.add("Pencil sharpener");
    products.add("High lighters");
    products.add("Markers");
    products.add("Erasers");
    products.add("Binder");
    products.add("Notebooks");
    products.add("Index cards");
    products.add("Folders");
    products.add("Glue");
    products.add("Ruler");
    products.add("Scissors");
    products.add("Calculator");
    products.add("Calendar");
    products.add("Backpack");

    for (String i: products) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static int searchProducts(int[] products) {
    System.out.println("enter all names of product");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = input.nextLine();

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        if (products][i] == x)
        return i;

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: what is the specific problem/error?

Comment: The second method named searchProducts. I want to let the user to type in the product name which will use linear search to identify if the product is in the array. But for some reason, it's not working.

Comment: In the second method you have array of `int[]` `products` and compare each _number_ in this array to the `String x`.  Do not you see what is wrong in comparing `int` to `String`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're using an ArrayList. To accept multiple parameters, take a look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_param.asp

Regarding your method, you should accept 2 parameters, not 1. In addition, you should accept an ArrayList, not a 1D array, and it should be of type String, not int.
Your method should look something like this:

```
public int searchProducts(ArrayList<String> arr, String str) {
    // you don't need to create a scanner object because the string you 
    intend to use is a parameter of the method
    
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        if(arr.get(i).equals(str)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
    
}
```

So now, if you want to call the method in your main(), you have to pass in your products ArrayList and the item you desire to find.

Comment: This loop can be replaced with standard `List::indexOf`.

Comment: Yeah, but he used a loop so I used one too.